# Carga icono o no en una celda de un jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, src

Tengo el siguiente código en mi jsp para cargar una tabla de registro en una pantalla:

```
<table name="tblListado" id="tblListado" datasrc="#xmlListado" style="table-layout:fixed;" dataPageSize="10" onreadystatechange="refrescarTabla();"><!-- style="visibility:'hidden';" -->
                                <tr>  

                                    <td align=center class=standtxtt width=19  style="padding:0px">
                                        <input name="optConfirma" type=radio onclick="guardarSeleccion(document.all('tblListado'))" >
                                    </td>
                                    <td align=left class="standtxtt" width=81 size="5"  ><!--tipo doc-->
                                        <span datafld="CDESDOBL"></span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align=left class=standtxtt width=100 size="10"  ><!-- doc-->
                                        <span datafld="FEFECTO"></span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align=left class=standtxtt width=200 size="20"  ><!-- doc-->
                                        <span datafld="ESTADO"></span>
                                    </td>
                                        <td width=50 class=standtxtt style="padding:0px; text-align:center">                                                
                                        <img src="../../multimedia/images/ico_caratula.gif" width="13" height="13" alt="" border="0" onclick="imprimirfaxfirma(this)">                           
                                    </td>                                               
                                    <td width=150 class=standtxtt onmouseover="oRutaFunciones.mostrarTitle(xmlListado,this,'CFAXFIRM');">
                                        <span datafld="CFAXFIRM"></span>
                                    </td>   


                                </tr>       
                                </table>
```

El cual en una columna le cargo una imagen por defecto. Lo que quiero es dependiendo del valor de una variable dicha imagen se cargue en esa columna o no (o que esté desactivada si es mejor) mediante codigo JavaScript.

¿Me podríais ayudar?

Si necesitáis más información no dudéis en decidmelo.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo dos ejemplos, uno ocultando la imagen en base a una variable y uno usando `classList.toggle` que me gusta mas.

```js
let muestraImagen = false;//<-- la variable que evaluamos

const imagen = document.getElementById("imagen");//<-- el selector de la imágen
const imagen2 = document.getElementById("imagen2");//<-- el selector de la otra imágen

document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", () => {//<-- ejemplo de un evento que dispara el cambio

  imagen.style.display = (muestraImagen) ? 'inline' : 'none';//<-- evaluamos la variable

  muestraImagen = !muestraImagen;

});

document.getElementById("boton2").addEventListener("click", () => {//<-- ejemplo de un evento que dispara el cambio

  imagen2.classList.toggle("hide");//<--solo agregamos o quitamos la clase

});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img id="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/3hDspWK.jpg" width="80" />
<button id="boton">
  muestra/oculta en base a una variable
</button>
<br>
<br>
<img id="imagen2" src="https://i.imgur.com/3hDspWK.jpg" width="80" />
<button id="boton2">
  muestra/oculta en base a clase
</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, aunque más que tener un botón para aparecer/desaparecer la imagen necesitaría que realizar cuando se cargue la pantalla.